# Binding data in windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I am beginner in Windows Phone.Please help me in this:-

This is the class which I extract from a service:-

```
public class Answer
{
    public string answerId { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string questionId { get; set; }
    public string questionTitle { get; set; }
    public string storyUrl { get; set; }
    public string correctAnswerId { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string questionType { get; set; }
    public string device_id { get; set; }
    public string quiz_type { get; set; }
    public int totalQuestion { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }

}
```

Now with the help of this, I want to bind questions in a text block & options in a radio button. 
I do following coding to deserialize json:-

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("my service url"));
```

I use this method: wc_DownloadStringCompleted()

and write this code

```
  var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

        val = rootObject.device_id;

        Question ques = new Question
        {
            questionTitle = rootObject.questions.Last().questionTitle,
            answers = rootObject.questions.Last().answers.Select(ans => new Answer { answer = ans.answer, answerId = ans.answerId }).ToList(),
            questionId = rootObject.questions.Last().questionId,
            storyUrl = rootObject.questions.Last().storyUrl,
            correctAnswerId = rootObject.questions.Last().correctAnswerId

        };
        txtQuestion.DataContext = ques.questionTitle;
        rb1.Content = ques.answers.ElementAt(0).answer;
        rb2.Content = ques.answers.ElementAt(1).answer;
        rb3.Content = ques.answers.ElementAt(2).answer;
        rb4.Content = ques.answers.ElementAt(3).answer;
```

this is how i got my last question from service

Scenario of my page is:-
on **submit** button click correct answer will display & a button **"Next"** is visible to display next question.

Please help me on this.....

Comment: what have you tried? do you expect us to do the entire work for you, design UI with XAML to be able to display multiple questions with multiple choices answer, then bind them to data from the web service? Nope, SO is not a free code service. And what happen with solution suggested in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21693618/2998271)? If you tried that, post how you tried, and what was the problem?

Comment: thanks for reply. i try to get questions & option in text block & radio button but i only get first question & their respective option.And please don't help me on designing xaml & displaying option i just want the concept that how to do this & if u know please share it.. & about my previous question the solution doesn't work at this moment.

Comment: so you managed to get the first question & respective options displayed, how you did that? Please post it, We'll consider that as an effort you have tried. And what you expect after that?

Comment: i edit my question & please help on this.....

Comment: Good, I can see how you display the last question now, then what is the problem/question? sorry if you think it is obvious, but I don't get it. Want to change your code to use data-binding instead? want to display all questions instead of the last (how you arrange all of them on screen)? want to be able to move to next/prev question?

Comment: Thanks for reply
my question is how we get correctAnswerId & answerId on a "Submit" button to check which option is correct & to change question on "Next" Button what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

Declare variable of type `Question` to hold index of current question displayed :

```
private int CurrentQuestionIndex;
```

Declare collection variable (use ObservableCollection instead of List if you plan to use data-binding later) to hold all questions from web service :

```
public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

Upon download json string completed set `CurrentQuestion` to the first question, and store all questions in `Questions` :

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
val = rootObject.device_id;
//store all questions
Questions = rootObject.questions;

DisplayCurrentQuestion();
```

Refactor your codes to display question into a function (`DisplayCurrentQuestion()`) so we can reuse it for displaying next question :

```
private void DisplayCurrentQuestion()
{
    Question ques = Questions[CurrentQuestionIndex];
    txtQuestion.Text = ques.questionTitle;
    rb1.Content = ques.answers[0]answer;
    rb2.Content = ques.answers[1].answer;
    rb3.Content = ques.answers[2].answer;
    rb4.Content = ques.answers[3].answer;
}
```

On button "Next" clicked simply change `CurrentQuestionIndex` to next question and display it :

```
CurrentQuestionIndex++;
if(CurrentQuestionIndex > Questions.Count)
{
    //this is the last question, no next question available
}
else DisplayCurrentQuestion();
```

"*how we get correctAnswerId & answerId on a "Submit" button*".

You can get it this way :

```
Question ques = Questions[CurrentQuestionIndex];
var correctAnswerId = ques.correctAnswerId;

if(rb1.IsChecked && ques.answers(0).answerId == correctAnswerId)
{
    //selected answer is correct answer
}
//else check next radio button
else if(rb2.IsChecked && ques.answers(1).answerId == correctAnswerId)
{
    //selected answer is correct answer
}
....
....
```

Note that there is another way around to do the same with Data Binding and following MVVM pattern, so consider changing the Title because your current code is not using data binding and this answer is not using data binding too.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my problem. I got my answer from this concept